# What's wrong with this piece of code? I don't know how to solve this issue

Tags: javascript, html, custom-attributes

Trying to create an element with some custom properties

```
function x(){
    var f=document.createElement("div");
    this.name="monkey";
    return f;
}
x.prototype.myFunction=function(){
    alert(arguments[0]+this.name);
};
var c=new x();
c.myFunction("hello");
```

The browser says that c.myFunction is not a function

Comment: The formatting is the first thing wrong.

Comment: Don't return anything. You are using it as a constructor, so it will automatically instantiate it as a new object.

Comment: This appears to be a very confused question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning an HTML element in your function, so `c` will have a reference to the element and not your object.

Remove `return f;` and you'll get your expected output of an alert box containing 'hellomonkey'

Comment: But then I get the error that there is no `appendChild()` method when I call `x.appendChild(document.createTextNode("I am a monkey"))`;

Comment: so define `this.that = $(this);`, then use `x.that.appendChild();`

Comment: @Billy Mathews, introducing jquery into this question is not useful.

Comment: @Xotic750 You're right, for some reason I thought `.appendChild` was a jQuery method. So change to `this.that = this;`

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok for you?

```
function x(){
  var f=document.createElement("div");
  this.name="monkey";

  this.myFunction=function(){
    alert(arguments[0]+this.name);
  };

  this.returnDiv = function() {
    return f;
  }

  return this;
}
var c=new x();
c.myFunction("hello");
```

Comment: I want to inherit that property but I want to make an Element